# functional Tests are failing to authenticate using Azure Active Directory on the build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, specflow, functional-testing, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a problem running functionality tests(SpecFlow with Nunit) on the pipeline, all my test requires Azure AD login in order to perfom any functionality, I have more than 40 tests of which all of them are running on my local pc via visual studio, but when i am running them on the build pipeline agent, only 4 out of 40+ test are passing, all the failing tests they seem to be failing at the Azure AD login Screen

Comment: How are you logging in to Azure AD locally? You may need to set up Azure AD login via Powershell, if this is a necessity for your application/organization.

Comment: I am loggin in the same way, i go to my home url then it redirects to login.microsoft.com login, i enter the details using selenium, then after i am authenticated it the redirects me to the my home application.

Comment: someone recommended that i login to azure azure AD via and API not via GUI, but i am unable to find a documentation about that.

Comment: Yes, you should log in via the API. Something like this should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-5.8.0 "Sign in with Azure PowerShell"

Answer (score 1):

> functional Tests are failing to authenticate using Azure Active Directory on the build pipeline

You could use the [Resource Owner Password Grant to authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) Azure Active Directory, but this is not recommended for production usage in real UIs though.

Source refer: [Unit Testing ASP.NET Core AAD Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064896/unit-testing-asp-net-core-aad-auth)

Alternatively, you could also create your private agent:

[How to create private agent](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Fagents%2Fv2-windows%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26viewFallbackFrom%3Dvsts&data=04%7C01%7Cv-lileu%40microsoft.com%7C9f010a52c678414e5f9408d8e940036f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637515808436900668%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=UeJyoL1ZX2rKp1fjO5dO6sYnPfypWFPqhSwvcWAfmjs%3D&reserved=0)

And if you have UI test in your test, please make sure run your self-hosted agent as an interactive mode and a [special configuration of the agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-mode) is required.